# Unhandled rejection Error: WHERE parameter “number_phone” has invalid “undefined” value

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm doing a login app with reactjs and express js and sequilize , when i test it with postman api everything is working but when i tried it with reactjs it give me this problem in the back end

**model/user.model.js**

> Code in backend

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('users', {
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    number_phone: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  });

  return User;
}
```

**router/verifySignUp.js**

> Code in backend

```
const db = require('../config/db.config.js');
const config = require('../config/config.js');
const ROLEs = config.ROLEs; 
const User = db.user;
const Role = db.role;

checkDuplicatePhone = (req, res, next) => {
  // -> Check Username is already in use
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      number_phone: req.body.number_phone
    } 
  }).then(user => {
    if(user){
      res.status(400).send("Fail -> Phone is already taken!");
      return;
    }
      next();
  });
}

checkRolesExisted = (req, res, next) => {  
  for(let i=0; i<req.body.roles.length; i++){
    if(!ROLEs.includes(req.body.roles[i].toUpperCase())){
      res.status(400).send("Fail -> Does NOT exist Role = " + req.body.roles[i]);
      return;
    }
  }
  next();
}

const signUpVerify = {};
signUpVerify.checkDuplicatePhone = checkDuplicatePhone;
signUpVerify.checkRolesExisted = checkRolesExisted;

module.exports = signUpVerify;
```

**controller/controller.js**

> Code in backend

```
const db = require('../config/db.config.js');
const config = require('../config/config.js');
const User = db.user;
const Role = db.role;

const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
    // Save User to Database
    console.log("Processing func -> SignUp");

    User.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        number_phone: req.body.number_phone,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8)
    }).then(user => {
        Role.findAll({
            where: {
                name: {
                    [Op.or]: req.body.roles
                }
            }
        }).then(roles => {
            user.setRoles(roles).then(() => {
                res.send("User registered successfully!");
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send("Error -> " + err);
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send("Fail! Error -> " + err);
    })
}

exports.signin = (req, res) => {
    console.log("Sign-In");

    User.findOne({
        where: {
            number_phone: req.body.number_phone
        }
    }).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).send('User Not Found.');
        }

        var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
        if (!passwordIsValid) {
            return res.status(401).send({ auth: false, accessToken: null, reason: "Invalid Password!" });
        }

        var token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, config.secret, {
            expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
        });

        res.status(200).send({ auth: true, accessToken: token });

    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send('Error -> ' + err);
    });
}

exports.userContent = (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        where: { id: req.userId },
        attributes: ['name', 'number_phone'],
        include: [{
            model: Role,
            attributes: ['id', 'name'],
            through: {
                attributes: ['userId', 'roleId'],
            }
        }]
    }).then(user => {
        res.status(200).json({
            "description": "User Content Page",
            "user": user
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            "description": "Can not access User Page",
            "error": err
        });
    })
}

exports.adminBoard = (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        where: { id: req.userId },
        attributes: ['name', 'number_phone'],
        include: [{
            model: Role,
            attributes: ['id', 'name'],
            through: {
                attributes: ['userId', 'roleId'],
            }
        }]
    }).then(user => {
        res.status(200).json({
            "description": "Admin Board",
            "user": user
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            "description": "Can not access Admin Board",
            "error": err
        });
    })
}

exports.managementBoard = (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        where: { id: req.userId },
        attributes: ['name', 'number_phone'],
        include: [{
            model: Role,
            attributes: ['id', 'name'],
            through: {
                attributes: ['userId', 'roleId'],
            }
        }]
    }).then(user => {
        res.status(200).json({
            "description": "Management Board",
            "user": user
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            "description": "Can not access Management Board",
            "error": err
        });
    })
}
```

I try that just in postman.

> POST : http://localhost:4242/auth/signup

**Unhandled rejection Error: WHERE parameter "number_phone" has invalid "undefined" value**

Thanks !

Comment: "Gives me this problem"... *what problem?*. This is a TON of code: And your question isn't clear. See creating a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry it's my first post in StackOverflow... When i test my route on POSTMAN for register an user, i have this error on my terminal :
**Unhandled rejection Error: WHERE parameter "number_phone" has invalid "undefined" value**

Answer (score 7):

From [Sequelize 5.0](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/upgrade-to-v5.html) on, you cannot have an `undefined` key in your `where` clause:

> Sequelize will throw for all undefined keys in where options, In past versions undefined was converted to null.

Make sure you are passing `number_phone` in the body of your request or add `|| null` to the where clause to default to null.

Comment: Yes, and it also happens when using `req.body` instead of req.query in a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

If you made your request on **Postman** and everything its ok, you probably need to check the **frontend** or **the client**.

Sometimes we need to **declare** the **kind** of **application type** for make a successful request

And just to check, review your **CORS** configuration to be able to do any request from you want to do that

**Here a some documentation for Express and CORS**

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

**And here AXIOS documentation for your request on the frontend**

https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example